# DataMapper, how to create multiple records?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

My example datamapper class

```
class Simple
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property  :id, Serial
  property  :uid, Integer
end
```

And I have an array id uid's I would like to add.

```
items=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]
```

If I wanted to search for any of the id's in the array I would do something like

```
Simple.all(:uid.in=>items)
```

Is there a way to do the same for creating multiple records such as:

```
Simple.create(:uid=>items) #this doesn't work by the way
```

A way around this is:

```
items.each{|item|Simplel.create(:uid=>item)}
```

But this can't be efficient,there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easier way in DataMapper. Most ORMs don't bother with bulk operations because they often require database-specific implementations. One of the few ORMs that does is SQLAlchemy: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html#executing-multiple-statements

Comment: Once you have to work with other ORMs, you appreciate even more how amazing SQLAlchemy is...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any bulk insert operations on the SQL layer. Think of the SQL database for which data_mapper is the abstraction layer. Mind you that each database author/manufacturer implemented its own tool (eg. SQLLDR for Oracle, BCP for MS SQL Server).

There is no way for the abstraction layer to bring this into a single interface.